# Typescript - create interface from list of property names

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to list all the properties in an interface at runtime but this doesn't look to be possible. So can I create an interface with a list of string property names?

Tried this but it doesn't work

```
interface MyInterface {
   prop1: string;
   propsList: MyProps;
}

type MyProps = "my_prop_1" | "my_prop_2"; //these types should be string


function addProps(){
   const myInterface: MyInterface = {
     prop1: "hello",
     propsList: {
       my_prop_1: "world",
       my_prop_2: "hello world"
     }
   }
}
```

Trying to use the interface results in

> Type {my_prop_1: string, my_prop_2: string} is not assignable to type 'MyProps'

I then want to be able to use `MyProps` later as a list of strings to check the properties in another list.

Is this possible?

Comment: Doesn't work *how*? What are you trying to do? What does "interface with a list of string property names" mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array of properties so you can use at runtime:

```
const myProps = ["my_prop_1", "my_prop_2"] as const;
```

Then you can get your old type `MyProps` like this:

```
type MyProps = (typeof myProps)[number];
```

And finally for your interface use a mapped type:

```
interface MyInterface {
   prop1: string;
   propsList: {
       [K in MyProps]: string;
   };
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of ```number``` here ```type MyProps = (typeof myProps)[number];```?

Comment: `myProps` is type `readonly ["my_prop_1", "my_prop_2"]`, so we can get the type of it using the `typeof` operator. We want a union of its elements so we use `[number]` to get all its elements in a union.